# How to await a DataTable().ajax.url().load()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, async-await

I my jQuery code, I need to load some data in a DataTable, and then, do stuff only after this DataTable has been properly filled.

My code currently looks like :

```
function f () {
    /* ... */
    $('#my_datatable').DataTable().ajax.url(my_url).load();
    /* Do some stuff */
}

f();
/* Do some more stuff */
```

And I want `/* Do some stuff */` or `/* Do some more stuff */` to be executed only after my DataTable is nicely displayed.

I am pretty new with javascript's asynchronicity, so I might misunderstand my needs, but I think I would like to do something like :

```
async function f () {
    /* ... */
    await $('#my_datatable').DataTable().ajax.url(my_url).load();
    /* Do some stuff */
}

f().then (function () {
    /* Do some more stuff */
});
```

This is what I usually do when I want to wait for a `$.get()` to be fully done.

Is there any way do do such kind of thing with DataTable's `.ajax.url().load()` ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a callback to the load method
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()

Example:

```
function f () {
        $('#my_datatable').DataTable().ajax.url(my_url).load(callback);
}
function callback(){
    alert('I am completely loaded');
}

f();
```

You can also nest your function in your callback.

Comment: Hot to pass setting and json to the call back function  as I can do at  " 'initcomplete':function(settings, jason){ //do staff } " ?

Comment: @infomasud 

`initComplete` can often be helpful to know when your table has fully been initialized, data loaded, and drawn, mainly when using an ajax data source. 
- https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete

If you need to use the settings data from the callback function, you can also run what you want done from the `initComplete` option since this will still run anyways when you use the `.load()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the built in [DataTables callback initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) if I want to run some code after the table has fully been initialised, data loaded and drawn.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
  }
} );
```

Comment: Well, this does work the first time I call a `.DataTable({ /* ... */ "initComplete" : /* Do some stuff */ })`. But the /* Do some stuff */ won't be triggered by a further `.DataTable().ajax.url("http://a.new.url").load()`